# memory error: "conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)"

Tags: memory, arduino, mysql-connector

Recently I dived into making an Arduino project. I use Arduino IDE 2.0.3 and the board, LILYGO T-PICOC3.

When I tried to let my board connect to the MySQL server, I encountered an issue...
This is my sketch. I uploaded it to the board successfully

```
#include <WiFiEspAT.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Button2.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/gpio.h"
//#include "MAX30105.h"
#include <Wire.h>
//#include "heartRate.h"

//#define I2C_SDA 12
//#define I2C_SCL 13


byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server_addr(xxx, xxx, xx, xxx); 
char user[] = "project" ;
char password[] = "1234";

WiFiClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

char ssid[] = "Home3";
char pass[] = "12341234";


// max30102 setup ----
//MAX30105 particleSensor;
//long lastbeat;
// max30102 setup ----


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // power supply ----
  pinMode(22, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(22,HIGH);
  // power supply ----
  

  // esp32 setup ----
  Serial2.setTX(8);
  Serial2.setRX(9);
  Serial2.begin(115200);
  // esp32 setup ----


  // max30102 segment ----
  //if (particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST) == false){
  //  Serial.println("MAX30102 was not found");
  //  while(true);
  //}
  //particleSensor.setup();
  //particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A);
  //Serial.print("max30102 is online!");
  // max30102 segment ----
  

  // WiFi start ----
  WiFi.init(Serial2);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  Serial.println("connecting to wifi");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1600);
  }
    Serial.println("Connected to network");
    pinMode(29, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(29, HIGH);
    IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
    Serial.print("My IP address is: ");
    Serial.println(ip);
  // WiFi start ----
  

  // connect to database ----
  Serial.println("Connecting to the database");

  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)){
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("unSuccessfully connect!");
  conn.close();
  // connect to database ----
}


void loop() {
   //long irvalue = particleSensor.getIR();

  //if (checkForBeat(irvalue) == true){
  //  long delta = millis() - lastbeat;
  //  lastbeat = millis();

  //  float beatsperminute = 60 / (delta/1000.0);
        
  //}


}
```

And I got the message from Output :

```
Sketch uses 340796 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 2093056 bytes.
Global variables use 69008 bytes (26%) of dynamic memory, leaving 193136 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Resetting COM5
Converting to uf2, output size: 714240, start address: 0x2000
Flashing G: (RPI-RP2)
Wrote 714240 bytes to G:/NEW.UF2
```

Everything seems fine so far... but as I check out the Serial Monitor, I receive a Memory error when the process reaches the code " conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password) "

```
12:33:29.765 -> Connected to network
12:33:29.810 -> My IP address is: 192.168.0.159
12:33:29.810 -> Connecting to the database
12:33:29.810 -> ...trying...
12:33:31.116 -> Memory error.
12:33:32.481 -> Memory error.
12:33:32.481 -> Error: -1 = unSuccessfully connect!
```

I was originally trying to integrate the Max30102 module into my board, but after the error occurred, I uncommented the code associated with Max30102 and try it again. In the end, It turned out the same. In addition, I change the “server_addr” for the other MySQL server and restart Arduino IDE and nothing changed too. Perhaps the problem is derived from the hardware, the libraries, or the potentially incomplete uploading?